# Exactly what type of programming language is R?

Tags: r

Like for example, python is fundamentally an object oriented language, i.e. everything including it's fundamental data types are objects. It supports all OO concepts like encapsulation, inheritance etc. Then on top of it has emulated procedural constructs and half-baked functional programming constructs like higher order functionals.

C is fundamentally a portable assembly language that allow abstract notions of targeting and manipulating memory using it's pointer language.

Wolfram language is fundamentally a term rewriter where it's fundamental data structure is expression with head and parts. It uses full pattern matching language like regex to define rules for it's expressions and uses infinite evaluation until its expressions stops changing, i.e. a fixed point is reached. Its general term rewrite allow it to emulate full procedural and functional language.

Now my question is what exactly is R language at a fundamental level? Does it have a fundamental representation of it's data types and everything? What is it's primary programming paradigm and what other paradigm it is just emulating? What programming constructs are completely available and what are half-baked?